# tengo problema de rutas con laravel al desplegar en servidor

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

**solamente puedo ver la ruta raiz**
la aplicación solo se visualiza desde la raiz pero al dar clic para navegar en el sitio todos los enlaces dicen not found, las rutas están con el helper route(), saludos.

Comment: Puede ser que estés teniendo problemas con el archivo htaccess

Comment: eso era amigo, solucionado.